# Hibernate Exceptions not propagated to Application deployed in JBoss 7.3

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jakarta-ee, wildfly

Issue: The Web application uses JPA/Hibernate to communicate with the Oracle database. This application is deployed in `JBoss EAP 7.3` and uses its Hibernate modules.

When an `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException` is thrown from hibernate, it is not caught in the catch block of the calling method. Due to this the service layer is not able to wrap the exception and propagate it to the UI layer.

Any help on this issue is really appreciated.

Comment: Do you use EJBs to implement the service layer? If yes - how do you configure transaction management?